# Testing Chrome's execCommand on localhost

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clipboard

At the top of my HTML page, I have declared the path to my Google Chrome extension:

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/thekey">
```

Further down, I inspect of the app is installed, and, if it is, execute a `copy` command (or `paste`, or `cut`):

```
if (chrome.app.isInstalled) {
     document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

I am trying to serve this page locally, and the URL in the address bar points to `localhost`. However, none of the clipboard features work. My app currently has the correct `clipboardRead` and `clipboardWrite` permissions, and of course the app is installed, but I think it's not executing because my localhost is not pointing to the site listed in `"app":"urls"`.

Is there any way that I can test locally if cut/copy/paste is working correctly through my extension?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to add the `localhost` to your extension's domains and comment it before minification, I guess. `.execCommand` executes perfectly fine on my localhost without any permission tweaks.

Comment: Is that so? Then perhaps I am doing something wrong elsewhere. No errors are being thrown by my execCommand, so I'm not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing a domain not listed in your `"apps" : "urls"` list, your permissions will naturally not exist on that domain.  Can't you just add `http://localhost/` as an app URL?  I know the Chrome Web Store won't allow it, but you should remove that when you're done testing anyway.

Comment: The file is actually hosted by the Chrome Web Store, so I don't think this is an option (without going through some hassle of "hosting" the manifest and changing references).

Comment: I just did a quick test and found that `execCommand` only works on pages listed in my URL list.  I don't fully understand you use case (do you not own the extenstion you're working with?  why not just load it as unpacked for testing? or is the app itself a development tool for use with localhost?), but I don't think you'll be able to use clipboard permissions on a non-listed URL.